# SymmetricDS taking so long to start

Tags: ibm-midrange, data-synchronization, symmetricds

I am trying to synchronize data between DB2(in AS400) and SQL Server using SymmetricDS.
I have configured DB2 as my master node and SQL server as client node. I have started my master node with the following command

```
sym --engine server --port 8084
```

It is taking nearly 50 minutes to start up. It spends a lot of time in two places while starting.

1. Checking if SymmetricDS tables need created or altered
2. Synchronizing triggers

Is this normal behavior or do I need to do something to make the startup faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour is normal, but the performance of your database seems not. A DBA should take a look at it and fix the issues.

Comment: Agreed.   Also, a side note.   You can turn off trigger sync at startup as well as the database check.  Set auto.sync.triggers.at.startup=false and auto.config.database=false in your engine properties file.